# I want alternative of navigator.permissions

Tags: javascript, permissions, geolocation, navigator

i have to seperate sending request and checking user`s permission

i`m developing a hybrid process that deals with location and map with javascript

but i had to seperate sending request and checking user`s permission

so i wrote script with 'navigator.geolocation' and 'navigator.permissions.query({name:"geolcation"})'

script written with permisssions api ran successfully with in the local environment but it failed in downloaded app with ios 17

so i want to find alternative of the script 'navigator.permissions'

can i find solution to my problems?

Comment: `navigator.permissions.query({name:"geolcation"})` should produce an error everywhere ... did you mean `navigator.permissions.query({name:"geolocation"})` - it definitely works in IOS since ios 16

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.